# How to Normalize Image

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing, normalization

I'm doing a job where I need to create an image from a model and signal, and I have these images as the result for signal 1 and 2, respectively:

[image: test with signal 1]

[image: test with signal 2]

But ideally I need to get something like this:

[image: image with signal 1]

[image: image with signal 2] I'm also accepting other methods or image processing to get the result.

I tried some basic normalization methods, but the better I could get is this:

[image: normalized image] that still has some noise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh, now it makes sense. Thanks! Why is the ideal case with brighter dots where the dots are dimmer in the image? I guess you want to detect the dots in the image, even the very dim ones, and ignore noise. I think the only way to do this is to consider a larger neighborhood, the signal dots have a specific shape to them, which you could turn into a template to find (eg via correlation).

Comment: What is the method you used to get the the result you show? What are these “normalization methods” you refer to? (I’m guessing the term has different interpretations in different fields.) It’s good to know what you tried, so we don’t write an answer recommending something you already tried and doesn’t work for you.

Comment: I used a sliding window, keeping the max values of it and setting the rest to 0.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You could try to normalize subimages of full image width and a height that has 1-2 of your point rows inside. Scale the whole subimage to pixel = (pixel - min)*(255/(max-min))

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you have a known model, maybe you can estimate the row-height from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all your images have the same top-down gradient in the signal strength, with a constant response horizontally, then you can normalize the response using something like this (psuedo-code, because I experimented with something other than Python and OpenCV, it should be easy to replicate this):

```
M = max(img, axis=1)  # the maximum value of each row
M = dilation(M, 15)   # each maximum has a larger reach
img = img / M         # normalize each row for the maximum intensity
output = img > 0.5    # some fixed threshold
```

After the normalization, the fixed threshold was able to extract each of the local maxima easily.

The 15 in the dilation (note that `M` is a 1D array at this point) would be the length of the 1D structuring element. This should be large enough to cover the gaps between the rows, 5 should be enough for the first example, the second needs maybe 10.

The idea here is that the row-wise normalization is easier to accomplish if you don't know how closely together the dots are on each row. This operation would be equivalent to applying a dilation to the image using a structuring element that is 15 pixels high and infinitely wide.

[image: result of operations above]